# Saving app specific images in in app data and not in camera default storage

Tags: android, media, android-sdcard

I'm using camera in my android app to click pictures and saving them in my app directory, using this:

```
 File mediaStorageDir = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath());
```

The image gets saved successfully to my app directory in internal storage.
But it also gets saved to my sdcard/dcim directory (which is my default camera pics storage location).

I tried capturing this location from sdcard, so that I can delete after capture, but unable to do so.
I don't want my app specific pics to be visible in gallery.

Comment: "The image gets saved successfully to my app directory in internal storage" -- no, it is being stored to external storage. [Internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) and [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) do not mean what you think they do. Beyond that, if you are having problems with your code, you need to show the code.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do like this:

```
String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "FolderName";
File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);
imagesFolder.mkdirs();
File image = new File(imagesFolder, "image.jpg");
fileUri = Uri.fromFile(image);
```

For capturing the picture form camera:

```
imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
startActivityForResult(imageIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

This will save your image to the gallery folder specified in IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, and not in default directory for Camera.

Now you will be able to manage the directory of your images and delete whatever image you want.